# Can I use Python to interact with an RF transmitter/controller?

Tags: python, hardware

I would like to build a RF transmitter/controller for my garage. When my vehicle gets within 25', I'd like for a computer to trigger a physical relay to open my garage door. you know, like Batman.

I like Python, so I'm hoping I can use it here.

Comment: This sounds a bit broad for SO; I'm sure there are Python modules that can interact with serial ports and so on (a quick Google search confirms that!), but the software is probably the easy part of this challenge...

Comment: http://www.embedds.com/controlling-hardware-spi-on-raspberry-pi-using-python/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in to the Raspberry Pi. It's a $25 embeddable computer than supports Python. You will need to spec an RF transceiver that can interface with the on board hardware and use the documentation to determine a control method.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into getting a basic arduino?  It sounds like you should pick up a cheap one at Radio Shack and get the RF devices to trigger your garage door opener remotely.  With the hardware, you can easily talk to it via python (though it'd be easy enough to just do with the Arduino language).

Comment: I was thinking a PC because i'd like to add more to it later. this is just the first task (garage opener). i guess i'll need to look into arduino more to see if its as expandable as I think i may need.